# Javascript - removing a class that was itself added by Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with some JavaScript, namely removing a class.

In general removing a class works fine.

However, if I have also added in the class via JavaScript, then it doesn't work. I am unable to remove it.

I imagine this is because the reference I have to the element and it's classes is set when the DOM is loaded, and that even though I can add a new class to the element and can see it in developer tools, when I try to remove it, it doesn't actually exist in the reference.

Code snippet is below:

```
this.nav = document.querySelector('.nav');

one.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    this.nav.classList.add("blue");
});

two.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    this.nav.classList.remove("blue");
    this.nav.classList.add("red");
});
```

So the result of this is that I can successfully add the class of 'red' to the nav element, but the blue is never removed.

Thanks

Comment: using `remove` won't care, please provide a minimal example of the issue.

Comment: You need to add enough (and **only** enough) code to show the problem. The code you have should work but I can think of half a dozen reasons off the top of my head why it might not depending on what you're doing.